# Determinant of non-square matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, linear-transformations

Suppose I have an linear transformation described by a square matrix $A$.
Then, $A$ takes a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to a vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ related to $x$ by the equation $y=Ax$.

Grant Sanderson defined the determinant of $A$ on his youtube series on linear algebra in the following way:

Two vectors $x$ and $y$ determine a unique paralelogram. On the same way $Ax$ and $Ay$ determine another paralelogram. The ratio between its areas is defined to be the determinant of $A$. That is $|\det(A)|=\text{Area}(Ax,Ay)/\text{Area}(x,y)$. (The sign of the determinant is given by the orientation of the vectors. If $A$ preserves orientation, its determinant is positive.)

Can't we define a determinant to non-square matrices by the same formula?

Link to Grant's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8VSDg_WQlA

EDIT: (Example)
Take 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad y=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Using the notation defined above, we clearly have $\text{Area}(x,y)=1$.
We have that $$Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}, \quad Ay=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$ too. So, $\text{Area}(Ax,Ay)=2$. Then the ratio between the areas is $2$, which coincides with the modulus of the determinant of $A$. (Of course $A$ changes the orientation of the vectors, so it's determinant is negative.)

EDIT 2: Here's an explicit definition of the determinant.
$$|\det(A)| =
  \begin{cases}
    \text{Area}(Ax,Ay)/\text{Area}(x,y)       & \quad \text{if } \text{kernel}(A) \text{ is zero}\\
    0  & \quad \text{if } \text{kernel}(A) \text{ is non-zero}\\
  \end{cases},$$
for any linearly independent vectors $x$ and $y$.

If $A$ preserves orientation, then $\det(A)>0$. $\det(A)\leq 0$ otherwise.

Comment: One can certainly define  a quantity as above, but it is not the determinant.

Comment: @copper.hat But it coincides with the determinant when $A$ is a square matrix right?

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro What about an $m\times n$ matrix with $n>m$? The determinant you defined is always zero?

Comment: @AlphaGo The quantity $\text{Area}(Ax,Ay)/\text{Area}(x,y)$ makes sense even if $n>m$. I don't see why that is a problem.

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro Will it depend on the vectors you choose in the definition?

Comment: I can prove that it does not in the $n=m=2$ case, but I don't know if it is always true.

Comment: It's straightforward to construct a $4 \times 3$ matrix with linearly independent columns such that $\text{Area}(Ax,Ay)/‌​\text{Area}(x,y)$ depends on the choice of vectors $x$ and $y$, so this is not even well-defined for a given matrix $A$. In any case, the generalization of the geometric interpretation of the determinant to higher dimensions is via parallelepipeds, not parallelograms; see this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/427576/32785

Comment: The formula $|\det(A)|=\mathrm{Area}(Ax,Ay)/\mathrm{Area}(x,y)$ only holds for $2\times2$ matrices. It fails even for square matrices of size $>2$.

Comment: Can you show an example?