# Prove that volume does not change for n-dimensional hypercube under a skew transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

And please, do not use the determinant, because I am trying to figure this out so that I can use it as a step in my proof that the determinant is the signed volume of a parallelepiped.

I am trying to rigorously prove this line:
"This corresponds to a skew translation of the parallelepiped, which does not affect its volume." for the answer from Hagen von Eitzen

A similar idea is used in James answer when he equates $det(v_1, v_2^\perp, ... v_n^\perp) = det(v_1, v_2, ... v_n)$

for this question here: [why determinant is volume of parallelepiped in any dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427528/why-determinant-is-volume-of-parallelepiped-in-any-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a skew transformation:
$$\mathbf{r}_1 = \mathbf{r}+(\mathbf r\mathbf u)\mathbf{v},$$
where $\mathbf{uv} = 0$, $|\mathbf u|=1$.

Consider chopping the initial parallelepiped by planes $\mathbf{ru}=c=\mathrm{const}$. Then the volume of parallelepiped is:
$$
V=\int_{c_\min}^{c_\max}S(c)dc,
$$
where $S(c)$ is the area of cross-section.

Then for every cross-section of a plane, the transformation is a translation $\mathbf{r}_1 = \mathbf{r}+c\mathbf{v}$. So the shape of cross-section doesn't change: $S(c)=S'(c)$ and thus the volume stays the same.